# Picketlink @RolesAllowed for roles assigned to groups

Tags: java, picketlink

Am using picketlink for an application and I would greatly appreciate if any one could help me out.

The application has many Groups (Admin, Customer Service etc) and each group can have many Roles (like Create a new User, Create a new employee, Launch a payroll process etc)

A user can be assigned to one or more groups, and a group to one or more roles. Normally I thought that a user assigned to a group will inherit all the roles of the group. If I use BasicModel.hasRole for a user assigned to a group, it returns true for all roles assigned to that group, which is as expected. However when using @RolesAllowed annotation on my rest end points, it will always return access denied exception for the same user. If there any workaround anyone can suggest? I want @RolesAllowed to allow users within a group having the allowed roles to pass through.

Or is there any other annotation I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these under the package org.picketlink.authorization.annotations:

```
@GroupsAllowed
```

Defines an authorization constraint where only members of a group is allowed to invoke a method.

```
@LoggedIn
```

Defines an authorization constraint where only authenticated users are allowed to invoke a method.

```
@PartitionsAllowed
```

Defines an authorization constraint that checks if the authenticated Account is stored within a partition.

```
@RequiresLevel
```

Defines an authorization check where only users with same or higher level then specified are allowed to invoke method

```
@RequiresPermission
```

Defines an authorization constraint that checks if the authenticated Account has a specific permission.

```
@Restrict
```

Defines an authorization constraint to a type or method using a Unified Expression Language.

```
@RolesAllowed
```

Defines an authorization constraint that checks if an authenticated Account is granted with one or more roles.

from here:
http://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/latest/api/org/picketlink/authorization/annotations/package-summary.html